# Search function in Outlook and attachements

Tags: malware, email, sandbox, email-attachments, outlook

I am wondering how the search function of Outlook is working, especially in regards to researching key words that are presents in emails attachements. Does the Outlook search function opens the files as it would do in preview mode? Or does it use some kind of "sandbox" mode to retrieve the text?

The targeted risk here would be the execution of malicious code placed in an attachement simply by a search function, where the user would not be able to assess whether the attachement is dangerous or not.

Comment: Which version of outlook are you talking about?  Outlook has been around since the very early versions of Windows and it's evolved a lot over that time.

Comment: I suppose the most recent one, Outlook 2016.